# Changing StatusBar orientation has no effect

Tags: xamarin.ios, orientation, statusbar

I have two ViewControllers - the main one is Portrait only - the second, which displays a WebView loaded with a YouTube video can rotate to any orientation. When it is dismissed in Landscape, returning to the main ViewController, the status bar is left in Landscape mode. I know when the YouTube view is dismissed and have placed the following line on code in the called method:

```
UIApplication.SharedApplication.SetStatusBarOrientation(UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait,true);
```

But it has no effect on the status bar. Is there some other place to set the orientation? Other ideas?

Thanks,
Rick

Comment: Is this issue fixed after rotating the device? I suspect it might be due to you not implementing the correct methods for orientation on all your controllers--I usually create a "base" controller for the entire app to fix these kinds of issues.

Comment: No - rotating the device does not fix the problem. Yes, I have one Master controller and the one controller for viewing the YouTube content - that's all.

Comment: I might have seen something crazy like this before.  Have you tried manually calling `WillRotate` and `DidRotate` manually after the YouTube content is dismissed?

Comment: Not sure where to try this call. In the Master controller it seems to have no effect.

Comment: Can you put a simple project up somewhere reproducing it? I think some code is needed to help solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the problem by adding the following to the AppDelegate

```
public override UIInterfaceOrientationMask GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations (UIApplication application, UIWindow forWindow)
{
     return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.AllButUpsideDown;
}
```

Then this code actually did what it is supposed to:

```
UIApplication.SharedApplication.SetStatusBarOrientation(UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait,true);
```